# Put phone in vibrate in android Code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to activate vibrate in android but evrey time i press the button the app crash.....

```
silet.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE)
```

also i did the import thing.
and declare :

```
public AudioManager silent;
```

Logcat:

```
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at com.android.hello.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:25)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925):    ... 11 more
07-13 22:06:17.956: E/AndroidRuntime(11925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: If it's crashing, post the LogCat error as well as the actual code method (not just one line).

Comment: Thank you for the logcat, but it is incomplete... Please post the entire logcat since it appears the root cause of your problem is not cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess, but you declared:

```
public AudioManager silent;
```

Have you initialized it with:

```
AudioManager silent = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

And you spelled `silent` wrong here:

```
silent.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
//silet.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you

```
       AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

       audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Need to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Enjoy!!!