# Switching sound profiles between ring and vibrate by code in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, vibration

I am developing a C# Windows Phone 8 application in Visual Studio 2012. I want to activate and deactivate "vibration". How could I achieve this ?

Thank you.

P.S: I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476703/put-phone-in-vibrate-in-android-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Windows Phone API does not allow for this. This [requested feature](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1908267-extend-the-api-to-query-phone-volume-and-vibration) has also not been added to the Windows Phone 8.1 API. The only thing that you could do is request the feature [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1908267-extend-the-api-to-query-phone-volume-and-vibration) and hope that MS might one day do it.

The link that you mentioned in your question is for Android, not WP8. WP8 does not allow for this as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the current SDK.

Comment: I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476703/put-phone-in-vibrate-in-android-code) and thought its possible